# Angular + NGINX - Returning text from NGINX location block

Tags: angular, nginx, environment-variables, cloud-foundry

I'm working on an Angular application, that reads environment variables from PCF (Pivotal Cloud Foundry) using NGINX. Few of my environment variables are plain text.

Therefore, how to return text from a location block in NGINX?

Using the following returns text,

```
location / {
return 200 "Hello, how are you?";
}
```

However I'm not able to use the above location rule, because it is used by default NGINX configuration to serve index.html.

And if I use any other location rule, like the following,

**NGINX file:**

```
location /textcontent/ {
return 200 "Hello, how are you?";
}
```

**Angular environment.prod.ts file:**

```
public const environment {
envVariable: '/textcontent/',
}
```

**component.ts file:**

```
env = environment.envVariable;
```

Value stored in the above
**env**
variable is "textcontent" and not "Hello, how are you?".

Please let me know how to fix this.

Thank you.

Comment: maybe I am not seeing it but... what tells Angular to make an http get request to something/textcontent?? Is this a thing in Angular?  I can not see anything here: https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-application-environments Can you see the request in you access log of nginx?

Comment: The contents of the `environment.prod.ts` file is "baked in" at compile time, hence it'll never interact with your NGINX backend. As Timo suggests, you need to make an HTTP request to acquire data from your backend.